# Is there a way to import text file to datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files

Good day, i am importing text file to datagridview and i want to have the output like this

### LOT ADDRESS  |  NAME   | METER NUMBER

0123RR ROAD 6 | DOE, JOHN | 123ABC456789

text file looks like this

0123RR ROAD 6            DOE, JOHN  123ABC456789

the character count from address to name is 25 and 10 from name to meter number.

my code looks like this

```
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim vals() As String
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "TEXT FILE | *.txt |ALL FILES |*.*"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        For i As Integer = 12 To lines.Length - 1 Step +1

            'Dim newlines As String = lines(i).Substring(25, 20)

            vals = lines(i).ToString().Split(" "c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)


            Dim row(vals.Length - 1) As String


            For j As Integer = 0 To vals.Length - 1 Step 2

                row(j) = vals(j).Trim()


            Next j
            dt.Rows.Add(row)


        Next i
    End If
```

Thank you

Comment: Use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data into a `DataTable`, then bind that to the grid, preferably through a `BindingSource`.

Comment: TextFieldParser and BindingSource is definitely the way to go. // However,  I'm curious about your code. Why start at line 12? It also looks like you had the idea to use Substring as you could have extracted each field from the line this way using Substring(0, 25).Trim, Substring(26, 10).Trim, Substring(27).Trim set to variables and then GridView.Rows.Add(addr, name, meter). // Split is only good if you have delimiters rather than fixed lengths and the usage is .Split(New Char() {" "c}, ...)

Comment: @Catherine because the start of the data i needed is at line 12.